# translating an image at an angle in CSS3

Tags: css, css-transitions

How do I translate an image at an angle in css3? I know that we can give x and y coordinates in translate function but I want to translate several images radially from one point and I want symmetry in that and that's why I am trying to translate at an angle.

Comment: Please provide some code and some tests you already did. Do you mean translating to a certain distance in a certain direction given by an angle ([polar coordinates system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system))?

Answer (score 3):

You can rotate the element, move it in the X axis, and then rotate it back so that it display level

```css
div {
    width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
}

div:nth-child(1) {
    transform: rotate(20deg) translateX(100px) rotate(-20deg);  
}

div:nth-child(2) {
    transform: rotate(45deg) translateX(100px) rotate(-45deg);  
}

div:nth-child(3) {
    transform: rotate(70deg) translateX(100px) rotate(-70deg);  
}
```

```html
<div>20</div>
<div>45</div>
<div>70</div>
<div>base</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The css `transform` property accepts several different options for manipulating elements.

You do have as you mentioned the `translate` property which you can move images in 3 axis (x,y,z), but if you want to add angles to your `transform` you can use the rotate property, like so:

```
transform: rotate(15deg);
```

You can also add more complex rotations like 3d rotations:

```
transform: rotate3d(x,y,z,angle);   /* Defines a 3D rotation */
```

For more information you can check the documentation for the transform property on: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp